# pass a variable from javascript to ruby controller

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, geolocation

I am trying to use location coordinates in my controller via session or something like it. I get location coordinates in my javascript code but I can't pass it to my controller.
My code is;

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(GeoL);
function GeoL(position) {
     var x = position.coords.latitude;
     var y = position.coords.longitude;
}
```

I want to pass x and y to my controller. Does anyone have any idea how can I do?

Comment: Post it to a controller action via AJAX call.

Comment: I didn't use AJAX before. So I don't know AJAX. I will search and try. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Add two field field for your form:

```
<%=hidden_field_tag :lat %>
<%=hidden_field_tag :lng %>
```

And then set the hidden field:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(GeoL);
function GeoL(position) {
     document.getElementById('lat').value = position.coords.latitude;
     document.getElementById('lng').value = position.coords.longitude;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need add your value on your cookie by Javascript or add this value on an hidden field in your form.

Comment: could you write code sample? I tried some codes but I couldn't be successful.